# function not getting executed - IndexedDB , IONIC 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, indexeddb

**Brief Explanation:** in my below code, inside `ngOnInit()` , `opn.success = function()` gets executed after

> console.log("This line is executed first");

whereas, we want `opn.onsuccess = function()` to be executed first.

**Please help.**

```
 ngOnInit()
    {
    var opn = indexedDB.open("webDealer", this._globalvar.getvarDBVersion());
        opn.onsuccess = function() {
          var db = opn.result;
          var transac = db.transaction(['usrprfl'], 'readonly');
          var storeNm = transac.objectStore('usrprfl');
          var countRequest = storeNm.count();
          countRequest.onsuccess = function()
          {
            this.cnt = countRequest.result;
            if(this.cnt == 1 )
            {
              storeNm.getAll().onsuccess = function(event)
              {

                var rslt = event.target.result;
                this.usr = rslt[0].nm;
                this.pwd = rslt[0].pw;
                this.clicktyp ='AUTO';

              };
            }
            else
            {
              this.clicktyp ='MANUAL';
            }
          };
          db.close();
        };
console.log("This line is executed first");
    }

    OnLogon()
    {
    //... mycode
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to indexedDB.open resolves asynchronously. If you want that log message to appear only after the database opens, then you need to wait until the database opens. Right now your code does not wait.

Here is some example code of how you could wait:

```
function open(name, version) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var request = indexedDB.open(name, version);
    request.onsuccess = _ => resolve(request.result);
    request.onerror = _ => reject(request.error);
  });
}

async function ngOnInit() {
  var db = await open('webDealer', this._globalvar.getvarDBVersion());
  console.log("This line is no longer executed first");
}
```